# Install R Packages without internet

Tags: r, installation, package

I have installed R version R_2.14.1 on window and need to install some of the packages but my system does not have internet connection. Any idea of how to install R package without internet.

Thanks

Comment: Please note that the latest version of R is 2.15, so you might want to update that too.

Comment: I'm assuming you have another system which is networked and can at least download packages to that machine...

Answer (score 21):

You can do

```
install.packages(".../path/to/package.tar.gz", type="source",
repos=NULL)
```

Which is described also [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Windows-7-installation-of-qz-package-from-SourceForge-td4348604.html).

Comment: @user395882 -- Since this worked, you can 'accept' the answer (and those of other questions that have been well answered for you) by clicking the check-mark just to its left.