# Zipping an R package with its imports/depends

Tags: r

I am working on a package, and it imports the development version of the `DT` package from github as well as several other packages. If I want to distribute my package to a computer that does not have internet access, is there a way I can zip my package with all of its imports/depends so that I don't have to distribute separate zips for each of the packages that it imports/depends, and install each of the packages separately?

It would be nice to have a single tar.gz that contains everything. Is this possible?

Kind Regards

Comment: Did you google about this ? Here are some relevant hits...(1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528630/install-r-packages-without-internet (2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807804/offline-install-of-r-package-and-dependencies

Comment: Yes I know how to install a package without the internet with a zip. My question is can I include all packages dependencies in the same zip?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you use an R kernel for jupyter, and Conda installation, there is a way to create and distribute R bundle

Please read "Creating your custom R bundle", link: https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer/jupyter-and-conda-r